# ¿Cómo obtener o traer datos a un formulario, de un usuario previamente registrado?, PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un formulario donde el usuario se registra previamente donde solo le pido tres campos de la tabla usuario. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Registro.php

```php
<?php
    include_once 'conexion.php';

    //Establecer conexión
    $db = new Database();
    $conexion = $db->connect();

    $NIT = $_POST['TxtNIT'];
    $nombreEmpresa = $_POST['TxtNombreEmpresa'];
    $correo = $_POST['TxtCorreo'];
    $password = sha1($_POST['TxtNIT']);
    
        //----- Insertar o guardar datos en la tabla usuarios
        $pst =$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_usuarios(user_pkid, user_ddi, user_nombres, user_correo, user_password, user_estado, user_fechaUser) VALUES ('$NIT', 'NIT', '$nombreEmpresa', '$correo', '$password', 'Activo', CURRENT_DATE);");
        $pst->execute();
                    
        //----- Cargar la pagina para completar registro -----
        header('location: ../frontend/Frm_InfoEmpresa.php');
        
        //Traer los datos de registro y declararlos en variables para cargarlos en el formulario siguiente
        $consulta = $conexion->prepare ("SELECT user_pkid, user_nombres, user_correo FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE user_pkid = '$NIT'");
        $consulta->execute();

        $row = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        if($row == true){
        //validar rol
        $_nit = $row[0];
        $_nombreE = $row[1];
        $_correo = $row[2];
        }
    }
?>
```

luego le pido al usuario que termine de completar el registro en otro formulario, entonces los datos que ingreso en el formulario anterior y los guardo en la base de datos quiero que los cargue o los traiga en el nuevo formulario para rellenar el resto de los campos y completar el registro en la misma tabla usuario. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Frm_InfoEmpresa.php

```html
            <form>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputNIT">NIT</label>
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_nit ?>" name="TxtNIT" class="form-control" id="inputNIT" placeholder="Ingrese el NIT...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputEmpresa">Nombre empresa</label>
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_nombreE ?>" name="TxtNombreEmpresa" class="form-control" id="inputEmpresa" placeholder="Nombre empresa">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputContacto">Contacto</label>
                        <input type="text" name="TxtContacto" class="form-control" id="inputContacto" placeholder="Numero de telefono">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputCorreo">Correo</label>
                        <input type="email" value="<?php echo $_correo ?>" name="TxtCorreo" class="form-control" id="inputCorreo" placeholder="empresa@mail.com">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputDpto">Departamento</label>
                        <input type="text" name="TxtDpto" class="form-control" id="inputDpto" placeholder="Seleccione departamento...">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputDireccion">Direccion</label>
                    <input type="text" name="TxtDireccion" class="form-control" id="inputDireccion" placeholder="Calle 0 # 0 - 0">
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-75">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-75">Actualizar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo dudas al respecto pero mi analisis es lo siguiente, en ese form donde estas imprimiendo esta incluyendo el archivo .php donde hiciste la consulta?, porque si te dice undefined es porque no encuentra esas variables en php

Otra cosa, intenta tambien en la parte donde colocaste:

$consulta->execute();

Intenta guardar eso en una variable y ahi si aplicas a ver que te sale.

$query = $consulta->execute();

$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

Comment: Olvide aclarar ese punto, el Registro.php  pertenece a otro form (Frm_Registro) donde solo pido el dato Nit, NombreEmpresa y Correo como lo puedes ver en la primer imagen, pero si el en otro form (Frm_InfoEmpresa) de la segunda imagen, que es para completar el registro incluyo Registro.php me pide los datos Nit, NombreEmpresa y Correo ingresado por Campo de texto (POST) y me manda error por que no los he definido, pero acá ya no necesito ingresarlos por campo de texto, si no que me los traiga de la base de datos, del usuario que hizo el registro anteriormente, no se si me hice entender.

Comment: Si entiendo pero intenta lo que dije, porque que pasa que en la variable consulta estas como guardando en la row solo la sentencia o la consulta en si pero no la estas guardando ya cuando se ejecuta, prueba a ver a si te funciona guardando el $consulta->fetch en una variable, y tambien revisa en la bd si realmente se estan guardando en la bd es importante que tambien valides si algo te llega nulo o no como un condicional

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo que debes de realizar es si tu valor es null:

Ejemplo

```
<input type="text" value="<?php if($_nit == null || $_nit == '' || $_nit == undefined ){ echo "" } else { echo $_nit } ?>" name="TxtNIT" class="form-control" id="inputNIT" placeholder="Ingrese el NIT...">
```

***Algo por el Estilo lo que estas revisando es que***

1. si la variable $_nit no esta definida entonces debe de rellenar el
   usuario
2. si esta definida entonces le muestra el valor del $_nit

Comment: Eso es lo que quiero lograr porque la variable $_nit la tengo en el Registro.php, como hago para instanciar o traer esa variable al Frm_InfoEmpresa.php?, por que si le doy include_once 'Registro.php' dentro del Frm_InfoEmpresa, me da error por que me pide el campo NIT, NombreEmpresa y Correo por texto o POST, y ya esos datos lo ingrese anteriormente en el registro como se ve en la primer imagen, por lo tanto en el Frm_InfoEmpresa no van a estar definidas.